# Angular HTTP get request returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, http-parameters

I am trying to make an HTTP get request at takes a userId as a parameter and returns a single user profile using Angular, but keep getting undefined data returned. I know the problem isn't with my backend server because the same HTTP get request with Postman
[works correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsUl8.png)
Also, I am getting
[this exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcPLW.png)
(backend is written in Java) from my Angular HTTP request, but not from the Postman HTTP request.

profile.component.ts:

```
profile: Profile;
constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) {
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.getProfile();
}
getProfile() {
  this.profileService.getProfile("5e7bd87e05854a05cc0f6898").subscribe(
    profile => this.profile = profile,
  );
  console.log( this.profile );
}
```

profile.service.ts:

```
getProfile(userId: string) {
    let params = new HttpParams().set("id", userId);
    console.log( "executing HTTP get" );

    //return this.httpClient.get<any>( "http://localhost:8080/user", { params: params });
    // I've tried this above method and the one below

    return this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:8080/user", { params: params })
    .pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        const profile: Profile = new Profile( data.object.id,
                               data.object.username,
                               data.object.password,
                               data.object.fname,
                               data.object.lname,
                               data.object.email,
                               data.object.joined );
        return profile;
      })
    );
   }
```

The `console.log( this.profile )` just comes out as `undefined` in the browser console. I think I'm using `subscribe` incorrectly. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6v5A.png)
from the browser console. Not sure if it's relevant.

Comment: What is the EXACT error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call `this.profileService.getProfile()` returns an Observable that is `async`. So the call flow is doing this:

- `this.profileService.getProfile("5e7bd87e05854a05cc0f6898")` starts the HTTP request
- `console.log(this.profile)` gets called (It is `undefined` because it hasn't been set yet)
- *sometime in the future:* the HTTP requests finishes
- *THEN*, your callback function in your `.subscribe()` runs. (in your case `profile => this.profile = profile,`)

To fix your issue, just move your `console.log` into your `.subscribe()` callback.

```
getProfile() {
  this.profileService.getProfile("5e7bd87e05854a05cc0f6898").subscribe(profile => {
    this.profile = profile;
    console.log( this.profile );
  });
}
```

I am not sure how that error is related because you haven't posted your `notifications.service.ts` code. It could be related to how you are setting the profile, 
but I cannot tell without seeing that other code. Same for the Java error. Not sure what the difference is between your Postman request and your Angular request.

Fixing the `console.log` will solve your `undefined` error. Hopefully that will help you figure out the Java error. 
That Java error appears to be related to a Web Socket or something. Just taking a wild guess, 
but I doubt your HTTP call to fetch your user's profile is causing that error.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yeah I just remembered the notifications error is because it's a microservice that wasn't running at that time. The problem is fixed but the Java error is still present so it must be unrelated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a recommendation as to how to access that profile information from the html code AFTER the request has been completed?

Comment: Do you have an existing `profile.component.html` file you want to share? The best way to _safely_ is to use Angular's [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) `?`. 

For example, in your html: 
`<p>{{profile?.name}}</p>`
That won't display anything until `this.profile` is loaded. It also won't error if `this.profile` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP requests are resolved asynchronously so when you print  `console.log( this.profile );` the GET request is still not resolved and therefore the value assigned to `this.profile` is still undefined. If you want to see the value just put the `console.log( this.profile );` inside the subscribe after you are doing the assigment `profile => this.profile = profile,`.

Comment: I changed it to `subscribe( profile => this.profile = profile, console.log( this.profile ); );` but I am getting compilation errors, what exactly would be the correct syntax?

Comment: You have to wrap your arrow function in brackets since you have two lines in your callback function. See my answer with the brackets in the callback.

Comment: And like this? this.profileService.getProfile("5e7bd87e05854a05cc0f6898").subscribe(
    profile => this.profile = profile; console.log(profile');
  );